# jquery How to queue ajax call one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I get this code looks better:
Currently I have something like this:

```js
$.when(
  ajax
).then(function(){
  $.when(
    ajax2
    ).then(function(){
      ...
    })
})
```

I want to get smt like this, but it doesnt work that way:

```js
$.when(
  ajax1
).then(function(){
  ajax2 //called when ajax1 is done
).then(function(){
  ajax3 //called when ajax2 is done
);
```

Comment: Doesn't appear you are returning anything from each `then`. Please show real code sample

Comment: Are you meant to be doing anything with the returned promise data inbetween all those calls?

Comment: charlietfl: thanks, missed return :)